# How to go from one list to another in a console-app?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a list that has four different types of products. Each type of product has their own unique items. For example, one type of product is "Electronics", and inside of that should be several electronic products (phones, accessories, etc), **which the user will manually enter themselves.**

But I can't seem to find a way to use a list to go into another empty list that would get this done. I have been looking into linked list but so far I haven't come up with much. My only other solution is to create five separate arrays but that seems like a bad solution.

I have one script which gets and returns my variables (string name, string productType, int categoryNo), another with my code and my main script which has this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Tools aTool = new Tools();

            aTool.Insert("Product One", "Electronics", 111);
            aTool.Insert("Product Two", "Crafting", 222);
            aTool.Insert("Product Three", "Cooking", 333);
            aTool.Insert("Product Four", "Construction", 444);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number based on the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("1: View Products");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Add Products");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Quit");
            Console.Write("\nSelect an option: ");

            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            if (name == "1")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                aTool.Display();
            }

            if (name == "2")
            {
               //Go to specific category
                Console.Clear(); // <-- temp code
                
            }

            else if (name == "3")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

I was thinking of adding a "code" to each product category, and then the user can type in a code to go to the respective screen, but I just don't know how I could make the user manually enter a product (using the above variables) and have it save into a new list. I do have a list length as well which is currently set to [4].

Comment: Is this a personal project or a task?
If it is personal, you could look into Entity Framework.
If you just need it done, you could do something similar to what you would do with EF.
Have a class `Category`, and have it have a list of tools. That would be it
`List<Category> categories` and `category.tools: List<Tool>`

You are not limited with classes to create, no need to do hacking with strings

Comment: I'm going to answer this question under the assumption that it's a personal project. It will be a bit lengthy, and involve lots of changes, but it will teach you best practices and set things up to be easier to add more features to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm time-boxing myself to 30 minutes on this. There's a lot more I could do, but here's what I got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    // todo: convert to an enumeration to minimize string match fails over case or typoes
    private static List<string> ProductTypeList;

    // string here is the Product Type
    // This holds a List of tools for each Product Type
    // When you list items, you only do it for the currently selected Product Type
    // When you add a new item, you add it to the currently selected Product Type
    private static Dictionary<string, List<Tool>> Products;
    
    public class Tool
    {
        public string ProductType;
        public string Name;
        public int Id;
        
        public Tool(string productType, string name, int id)
        {
            ProductType = productType;
            Name = name;
            Id = id;

            // Absolutely none of the below should be managed inside the Tool class
            //   Tool should know nothing about ProductTypeList or Products, but this was crazy/fun to write!
            List<Tool> toolList;
            if (Products.ContainsKey(productType))
            {
                toolList = Products[productType];
            }
            else
            {
                ProductTypeList.Add(productType);
                toolList = new List<Tool>();
                Products.Add(productType, toolList);
            }
            toolList.Add(this);
        }
        
        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ProductType + " " + Id + ": " + Name);
            // The above should be the following, but I'm doing this in dotnetfiddle.net
            //Console.WriteLine($"{ProductType} {Id}: {Name}");
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProductTypeList = new List<string>();
        Products = new Dictionary<string, List<Tool>>();
        
        Tool t = new Tool("Electronics", "Product One", 111);
        t = new Tool("Crafting", "Product Two", 222);
        t = new Tool("Cooking", "Product Three", 333);
        t = new Tool("Construction", "Product Four", 444);
        
        string currentList = ProductTypeList[0];
        List<Tool> currentToolList = Products[currentList];

        Console.Clear();
        
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number based on the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("1: View Products for " + currentList);
            Console.WriteLine("2: Add Products");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Change Product List");
            Console.WriteLine("9: Quit");
            Console.Write("\nSelect an option: ");

            int id = 0;
            string selection = Console.ReadLine();

            int option = 0;
            Int32.TryParse(selection, out option); // if fail, option will be zero

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1: // View Products
                    Console.Clear();
                    foreach(var tool in currentToolList)
                    {
                        tool.Display();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2: // Add Products to current list
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("ID: ");
                    string idValue = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (name == string.Empty || idValue == string.Empty || !Int32.TryParse(idValue, out id))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Tool newTool = new Tool(currentList, name, id);
                    //currentToolList.Add(newTool);
                    break;

                case 3: // change current list
                    foreach(var product in ProductTypeList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(product);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a product list: ");
                    string productListSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                    if (productListSelection == string.Empty)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (Products.ContainsKey(productListSelection))
                    {
                        currentList = productListSelection;
                        currentToolList = Products[currentList];
                        Console.WriteLine("Current list updated");
                    }
                    break;

                case 9: // Exit
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.Write("Invalid selection");
                    break;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, you should make a `List<Tools>` and then "assign" each list of `Tools` a different type. I'm also going to cover that in my longer answer here, but that's the gist of how you solve this problem.

First, your `Tools` object. Instead of passing in a string and an id, let's make something called an `Enum` that is basically a string and id wrapped up into one thing. To follow with what you currently have, this `Enum` could look like this:

```
public Enum ToolType
{
    // You could set these to the numbers you have listed above, but having them set like this will help us later in the code
    Electronics = 0,
    Crafting = 1,
    Cooking = 2,
    Construction = 3,
}
```

You will need to change your `Tools` object to take a `ToolType` enum instead of the string. You can keep the string, and add some handling for that, but it would be easier for you if you just passed an enum. Enums have a `.ToString()` method that will convert their name (e.g. `ToolType.Electronics.ToString()` would return `"Electronics"`), and if you cast them to an `int`, it will return that number you set them to (e.g. `(int)ToolType.Electronics` would return 111)

Using your current code, declaring what you currently have would look like this:

```
aTool.Insert("Product One", ToolType.Electronics);
aTool.Insert("Product Two", ToolType.Crafting);
aTool.Insert("Product Three", ToolType.Cooking);
aTool.Insert("Product Four", ToolType.Construction);
```

Where it's unclear if you have a individual `Tool` object, let's add one. It could look like this

```
public class Tool
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public ToolType ToolType { get; set; }

    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return ToolType.ToString();
        }
    }

    public int Id 
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)ToolType;
        }
    }

    public Tool(string productName, ToolType type)
    {
        ProductName = productName;
        ToolType = type;
    }
}
```

Let's now change the `Insert` Method, and the `Tools` object itself a little bit. These changes will mean that we can change which category we are accessing, as they will be in individual lists.

```
public class Tools
{
    //Instead of a List<Tool>, we are going to have a List<List<Tool>> so we can separate them by category
    public List<List<Tool>> ToolsByCategory { get; set; } = new();

    public Tools()
    {
        // Unsure about your constructor, but this will need to be added to it so we have enough lists for each category.
        for (int i = 0; i < ToolType.GetNames().Count(); i++)
        {
            ToolsByCategory.Add(new List<Tool>());
        }
    }

    //This is a change to what the first line of insert would need to look like
    void Insert(string productName, ToolType toolType)
    {
        // This will add a new Tool to the appropriate List which holds only types of that one Category
        ToolsByCategory[(int)toolType].Add(new Tool(productName, toolType));
    }
}
```

Using this set up, accessing only a specific category just involves using the `int` of the tool type to get that specific `List<Tool>` from the `List<List<Tool>>`

For example, if I wanted a list of only the crafting tools, I would just do this: `List<Tool> craftingTools = Tools.ToolsByCategory[(int)ToolType.Crafting];`

I hope you find all of this helpful, and if you have any questions please leave a comment.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. I checked back but saw no new comments so I left it. I have been working for a whole day straight now (on my own) and have come up with a similar solution to you, but it's too large to paste here. I am able to create a second list however even with List<Tool>, the list does not save once I either exit the application OR go to a new screen and then come back. Not too sure how to ask for help here given the large amount of text to paste in

Comment: If you have new questions about individual problems, it would be good to ask a new question on the website, with your updated code.